# Configuring what is written to Kafka Topic when using Kafka Connect Cassandra Source

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am doing a spike in which we want to publish data as it is written in a Cassandra table to a Kafka Topic. We are looking at using Kafka Connect and the Stream Reactor Connectors.

I am using Kafka 0.10.0.1

I am using DataMountaineer [Stream Reactor](http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/install.html#install) 0.2.4

I placed the jar file for Stream Reactor into the Kafka libs folder and am running Kafka Connect in distributed mode

```
bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties
```

I added the Cassandra Source connector as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @config/connect-idoc-cassandra-source.json.txt localhost:8083/connectors
```

When I add data to the Cassandra table I see it being added to the topic using the Kafka command line consumer

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic idocs-topic --from-beginning
```

Here is a sample of what is being written to the Topic right now:

```
{
"schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [{
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "idoc_id"
    }, {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "idoc_event_ts"
    }, {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "json_doc"
    }],
    "optional": false,
    "name": "idoc.idocs_events"
},
"payload": {
    "idoc_id": "dc4ab8a0-fdf8-11e6-8285-1bce55915fdd",
    "idoc_event_ts": "dc4ab8a1-fdf8-11e6-8285-1bce55915fdd",
    "json_doc": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
}}
```

What I would like written to the topic is the value of the `json_doc` column.

Here is what I have in my config for the Cassandra source

```
{
"name": "cassandra-idocs",
"config": {
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceConnector",
    "connect.cassandra.key.space": "idoc",
    "connect.cassandra.source.kcql": "INSERT INTO idocs-topic SELECT json_doc FROM idocs_events PK idoc_event_ts",
    "connect.cassandra.import.mode": "incremental",
    "connect.cassandra.contact.points": "localhost",
    "connect.cassandra.port": 9042,
    "connect.cassandra.import.poll.interval": 10000
}}
```

How do I change the way Kafka Connect Cassandra Source is configured so that only the value of `json_doc` is written to the Topic so it would look something like this:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

The [Kassandra Connect Query Language](http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/kcql.html#why) seemed to be the way to go but it isn't limiting what is written to the column specified in the KCQL.

**UPDATE**

Saw this [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878365/why-is-meta-data-added-to-the-output-of-this-kafka-connector) and changed the converters in the `connect-distributed.properties` file from `JsonConverter` to `StringConverter`.

The result is this is now written to the Topic:

```
Struct{idoc_id=74597cf0-fdf7-11e6-8285-1bce55915fdd,idoc_event_ts=74597cf1-fdf7-11e6-8285-1bce55915fdd,json_doc={"foo":"bar"}}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Changed the converters in the `connect-distributed.properties` file back to `JsonConverter`. Then also disabled the schemas.

```
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

The result is this is now written to the Topic:

```
{
    "idoc_id": "dc4ab8a0-fdf8-11e6-8285-1bce55915fdd",
    "idoc_event_ts": "dc4ab8a1-fdf8-11e6-8285-1bce55915fdd",
    "json_doc": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
}
```

**Note**
Using code from snapshot release and changing the KCQL to

```
INSERT INTO idocs-topic 
SELECT json_doc, idoc_event_ts
FROM idocs_events 
IGNORE idoc_event_ts
PK idoc_event_ts
```

Yields this result on the Topic

```
{"json_doc": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"}
```

Thanks

Comment: You got the right answer. Good to see you figured it out :)

Comment: It is still not what we want. as ideally it would just be the value of the column json_doc. Also submitted two PRs so that KCQL would use the SELECT and IGNORE when crafting a response. I will change the result in UPDATE 2 to how it works with 0.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I was attempting to do was not possible in the Cassandra Source in DataMountaineer Stream Reactor 0.2.4. However, the snapshot release (of what I assume will become release 0.2.5) will support this.

Here is how it will work:

1) Set the converters in the `connect-distributed.properties` file to `StringConverter`.

2) Set the KCQL in the JSON configuration for the Cassandra Source connector to

```
INSERT INTO idocs-topic 
SELECT json_doc, idoc_event_ts 
  FROM idocs_events 
IGNORE idoc_event_ts 
    PK idoc_event_ts 
WITHUNWRAP
```

This will result in the value of the `json_doc` column being published to the Kafka Topic without any schema information or the column name itself.

So if the column `json_doc` contained the value `{"foo":"bar"}` then this is what would appear on the Topic:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Here is some background information on how the KCQL works in the snapshot release.

The `SELECT` will now retrieve only the columns in that table that are specified in the KCQL. Originally it was always retrieving all of the columns. It is important to note that the PK column must be part of the `SELECT` statement when using the `incremental` import mode. If the value of the PK column is not something that should be included in the message published to the Kafka Topic then add it to the `IGNORE` statement (as in the example above).

The `WITHUNWRAP` is the new feature to KCQL that will tell the Cassandra Source connector to create a `SourceRecord` using the String `Schema` type (instead of Struct). In this mode only the values of the columns that are in the `SELECT` statement will be stored as the value of the `SourceRecord`. If there is more than one column in the `SELECT` statement after applying the `IGNORE` statement then the values are appended to together and separated by a comma.